# Debezium Connector - read from beginning and stop working connector

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

I am trying to use Debezium to connect to my Postgres database. I would like to copy data from a specific table. Using this configuration I only copy the newest data. Should I only change a snapshot.mode?

```
    "name": "prod-contact-connect",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.user": "user",
        "database.dbname": "db_name",
        "slot.name": "debezium_contact",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
        "publication.name": "dbz_publication",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "database.server.name": "connect.prod.contact",
        "database.port": "5432",
        "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
        "table.whitelist": "specific_table_name",
        "database.sslmode": "disable",
        "database.hostname": "localhost",
        "database.password": "pass",
        "name": "prod-contact-connect",
        "transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "op,table,schema,name",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "snapshot.mode": "never"
    }
}
```

by the way, how can I stop working the debezium connector for a moment? There is some enable flag?

Comment: What happens when you try snapshot mode? And Kafka Connect API has a /pause endpoint

Comment: When i used snapshot.mode = never then, my connector only read data with filter as created_at connector >= updated_at record from original table. So i miss older records in destination table

Comment: Yes, and what happens when you change that to something else? Did you read the documentation that says when you use snapshot mode, it'll read all existing data, and then move on to the actively written records?